# Textarea doesn't expand to 100% width in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

The following code doesn't match the width of the `textarea` to the width of the `div` which is located underneath. Setting `min-width: 100%` or adding the bootstrap class `w-100` doesn't help either.

[image]

```
<div class="container p-5">
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% include 'core/edit_post/edit_post_header.html' %}
        <div class="row mt-4 form-group w-100">
            <label class="font-weight-bold" for="{{ form.text.id_for_label }}">Text</label>
            <textarea name="{{ form.text.name }}" cols="40" rows="10" maxlength="{{ form.fields.text.max_length }}"
                      class="textarea form-control" id="{{ form.text.auto_id }}"
                      placeholder="Enter your text"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            {% include 'core/edit_post/edit_post_file_upload.html' %}
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You are specifying width with `cols="40" rows="10"` on the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `w-100` from `<div class="row mt-4 form-group w-100">` solved my problem